# Is it possible to generate a single presigned URL which can allow MULTIPLE unique objects to be uploaded?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know based on the AWS docs here

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

that its possible to generate a URL which can can used to

> upload **a** specific object to your bucket

and that

> You can use the presigned URL multiple times, up to the expiration date and time.

It is also possible to generate a URL (perhaps a base s3 presigned URL) which would allow multiple different unique documents to be uploaded based on a single URL?

For example, lets imagine a client application would like to upload multiple unique/distinct documents to s3 using some type of presigned URL. I dont necessarily want to force them to get a batch of presigned URLs since that would require much more on the part of the client (they would have to request batch of presigned URLs, rather than a single URL)

Here is the flow for a single document upload.

[image]

[image]

What is the simplest known solution for allowing a client to use some type of presigned url to upload **multiple** documents?

Answer (score 4):

> It is also possible to generate a URL (perhaps a base s3 presigned URL) which would allow multiple different unique documents to be uploaded based on a single URL?

A presigned URL is limited to a single single object key. You can't, for example, presign a key of `foo` and then use it to upload `foo/bar` (because that's a different key).

That means that, if you want to provide the client with a single pre-signed URL, the client code will have to combine the files itself. For example, you require the client to upload a ZIP file, then trigger a Lambda that unpacks the files in that ZIP.

Another approach is to use the AWS SDK from the client, and use the [Assume Role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html) operation to generate temporary access credentials that are restricted to uploading files with a specified prefix using an inline session policy.

A third approach is to hide the URL requests. You don't say what your client application does, but assuming that you let the user select some number of files, you could simply loop over those files and retrieve a URL for each one without ever letting your user know that's happening.

Comment: "You don't say what your client application does" The client application is simple: It just uploads document(s) to s3 and in return gets the object URL(s) associated with the upload(s). Does this change that last part of the insights you provided?

Comment: Also, how exactly would the Assume Role operation work? Could you expand on this approach a little bit? Perhaps this is a better solution to solve the problem. I would need to determine how the client will authenticate with this approach: What credentials do they store? Is there an IAM user they are assigned?

Comment: @jbooker - does the user care about the URL, or is it just the application? If the user needs the URL to do something outside of the application, then you're out of luck; you need a URL per object.

Comment: Re assuming a role, what language(s) is used on the client and the server?

Comment: User or application? Hmmm, I mean the client is an application. C#

Comment: You have a person that uses the client program, right? Are you expecting that person to use the URL independently of your client application? For example, do you give the user a URL and then expect them to use `curl` to upload the file? My point is: if you don't actually show the URL to the user, then you shouldn't care how many URLs you get, or how they're used.

Comment: One argument I can see in favor of caring about how many URLs the client receives is the number of requests that would need to be made in order to upload a batch:of user has 100 documents, do we really want them to make 100 requests?

Comment: If they don't know they're making 100 requests, does it matter? There is, of course, going to be a time difference between uploading a single ZIP file and uploading 100 uncompressed files. How much of a difference that is, and whether it matters to your users, is something that only you can answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to upload multiple files with a single pre-signed URL and properly configured 'Starts-with' policy. Please, refer to the following AWS documentation: [Browser-Based Uploads Using POST](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html)

Comment: Even with `starts-with` condition, don't you still need to specify key that gets checked cryptographically with the signature? I've just tried setting `starts-with` condition and if I want to upload another file, I get back an s3 error: `AccessDenied` and `Invalid according to Policy: Policy Condition failed: ["eq", "$key", "original_key"].

Comment: The policy, which failed in your case is an exact match condition. You should have starts with condition instead, something like ["starts-with", "$key", "some_key_prefix/"]

Comment: Just to clarify, I am setting *only* ‘starts-with’ condition but it still fails due to a failed exact match (that I didn’t set myself). I found a recent SO question with very similar code that I used and they get the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71386041/pre-signed-url-for-multiple-files-boto3

Comment: The problem was in how I specify key parameter on the frontend. I assumed I should also put `"uploads/${filename}"` there instead of an actual filename. With an actual filename the conditions do not fail and everything works well  Sorry for the troubles and thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! Glad to hear that you managed to apply this approach :)

Comment: @the-lay   do you have a code snippet you can share? I'm also having difficulty making this work.

Comment: @RRoesler multi-line snippets are not rendered properly in the comments, so excuse the brevity, but hopefully this will help: `prefix = "path/to/parent/folder/"; response = boto3.client("s3").generate_presigned_post(S3_BUCKET_NAME, prefix + "${filename}", Conditions=[["starts-with", "$key", prefix]], ExpiresIn=UPLOAD_EXPIRATION_SECONDS )`

Comment: @the-lay Ah, it's a presigned POST. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for dotnet ?