# Pre-signed url for multiple files boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

after finding a solution for multiple files I came to know a solution which look like this

```
response = s3.generate_presigned_post(
        "BUCKET_NAME",
        "uploads/${filename}",
        Fields=None,
        Conditions=[["starts-with", "$key", "uploads/"]],
        ExpiresIn=(10 * 60),
    )
```

so now scenario is I am creating a folder on fly . like here my folder will be like  `upload/bulk_upload`    here I will allow user to upload multiple files . so In this code how I will do this ?  what will `${filename}` as files will be dynamic and what is `$key` in my case ? Confuse where I have to change to make this program run according to my wish

Answer (score 0):

> what will ${filename} as files will be dynamic

You can't do this. `${filename}` can't be dynamic and you must specify it upfront when you generate `generate_presigned_post`. So you have to run `generate_presigned_post` for each file you are going to upload.

For example, if you want to upload 100 files of different `${filename}`, you have to run 100 `generate_presigned_post`.

> what is $key in my case

`$key` is a constant. You don't change it. It is literal string `$key`. Its part of the syntax.