# How to upload huge folder to s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, frontend

I have a use case where my UI app has to upload a directory to S3, probably having 100k-ish small txt files.
Possible options I see:

1. UI requests for presigned URLs from backend, but since presigned URLs can only be used to upload a single object, we will need to create as many presigned URLs as the number of txt files (100k-ish).
2. Ask user to zip the file and upload single shot, but this will add friction on user's side. This will also need me to write a unzip-task because the consumer needs it extracted in s3.

I tried with the first approach mentioned in the body, the time taken in upload is impractical.

Comment: If your user is authenticated with AWS Cognito, you could use identity pool to grant a temporary iam role with access to put into yours s3. 

You can refer to this doc for more info. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/role-based-access-control.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to generate a single presigned URL which can allow MULTIPLE unique objects to be uploaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63040308/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-single-presigned-url-which-can-allow-multiple-uniqu)